# Avoid duplicated rows in SQL query when JOINing many to many tables

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, inner-join, aggregate-functions

I have a basic blog system with tables for posts, authors and tags.

One author can write a post but a post can only be written by an author (one to many relationship). One tag can appear in many different posts and any post can have several tags (many to many relationship). In that case I've created a 4th table to link posts and tags as follows:

```
 post_id -> posts_tag
|    1     |    1    |
|    1     |    2    |
|    2     |    2    |
|    4     |    1    |
```

I need a single query to be able to list every post along with its user and its tags (if any). I'm pretty close with a double JOIN query but I get duplicated rows for posts with more than one tag (everything in that rows is duplicated but the tag register). The query I'm using goes as follows:

```
SELECT title,
     table_users.username author,
     table_tags.tagname tag
  FROM table_posts
  JOIN table_users 
    ON table_posts.user_id = table_users.id
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_posts_tags 
    ON table_posts.id = table_posts_tags.post_id
  LEFT 
  JOIN table_tags 
    ON table_tags.id = table_posts_tags.tag_id
```

Could any one suggest an amend to this query or a new proper one to solve the row duplication issue* when there's more than one tag associated to the same post? Ty

(*) *To make clear: in the above table the query will throw 4 rows when it should be throwing 3, 1 for post #1 (with 2 tags), one for post #2 and one for post #4.*

**Table Recreate**

```
CREATE TABLE `table_posts` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `content` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
)

CREATE TABLE `table_tags` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name_tag` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `table_posts_tags` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `post_id` int NOT NULL,
  `tag_id` int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `tag_id` (`tag_id`),
  KEY `FK_t_posts_tags_t_posts` (`post_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_posts_tags_t_posts` FOREIGN KEY (`post_id`) REFERENCES `t_posts` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_posts_tags_t_tags` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`) REFERENCES `t_tags` (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `table_users` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `username` varchar(16) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT NULL,
  `banned` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `FK_t_users_t_roles` (`role_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_t_users_t_roles` FOREIGN KEY (`role_id`) REFERENCES `t_roles` (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: GROUP By or reduce the rows before joining that is depending on what your result is

Comment: Hi Strawberry. I'll try to provide the CREATE queries tomorrow from school. Ty!

Comment: Table creation added

Answer (score 0):

One option aggregates the tags in a CSV list using `group by` and `group_concat()`:

```
select p.title, u.username author, group_concat(t.tagname) tagnames
from table_posts p
inner join table_users u       on u.id = p.user_id
left join  table_posts_tags pt on pt.post_id = p.id
left join  table_tags t        on t.id = tp.tag_id
group by p.id, p.title, u.username
```

Note that I added table aliases to the query, and used them to qualify all columns; this makes the query shorter and easier to write and read.

Comment: Ty GMB but your solution does not keep the original table structure which, following the SQL theory for 'many to many' relationships should rely on 2 main tables and the connection one.

We've already considered the CSV solution but does not seem to follow the ideal data architecture. Please correct me if I'm wrong or it is simply impossible (for some theoretical reason) to solve it with our actual table design. Yes, we're at school! :-)

Comment: @hip: so which result do you want when a post has, for example, three tags?

Comment: Result should be the list of posts in their published order (equivalent  to ID order). Each item of the list would go as follows: 
Post title / Authorname / List of tags (e.g. separated by a blank space)

Comment: @hip: well, that's what the query does. The list of tags in comma-separated, but that can easily be changed.

Comment: blank space, comma, dash... any would do, that's not the problem

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow and check what does it do. I will also publish the CREATE queries for each of the 4 table. Ty!

Comment: Hi @GMB we've found making use of your suggestion won't let us choose easily posts by tag (or even authors who posted with this or that tag). On the other hand it's true we could do both, the CSV solution + the link table we already have, but it'd be redundant and against good practices, I bet.

FYI I've added the table creation queries as suggested by Strawberry